# ng new fails with yarn : Couldn't find package "@ngtools/webpack@1.10.2"

Tags: angular, archlinux, yarnpkg

I try to create a new angular project with ng-cli and yarn but it fails to find package @ngtools/webpack.

I've created an issue on github : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9992

Here is the result of the command :

```
$ ng set --global packageManager=yarn
$ ng new angular5-toh
  create angular5-toh/README.md (1027 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/.angular-cli.json (1247 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/.gitignore (544 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/environments/environment.ts (387 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/index.html (298 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/main.ts (370 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/polyfills.ts (3114 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/tsconfig.app.json (211 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/tsconfig.spec.json (283 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/typings.d.ts (104 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (294 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/e2e/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (235 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/karma.conf.js (923 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/package.json (1297 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/protractor.conf.js (722 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/tsconfig.json (363 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/tslint.json (3012 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/app/app.module.ts (316 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/app/app.component.html (1141 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (986 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/src/app/app.component.ts (207 bytes)
error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find package \"@ngtools/webpack@1.10.2\" required by \"@angular/cli@~1.7.3\" on the \"npm\" registry.".
Error: Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

But the package is available here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack

Then, i tried again in the directory but it fails again with another error

```
$ cd angular5-toh
$ yarn
yarn install v1.5.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find package \"@schematics/angular@0.3.2\" required by \"@angular/cli@~1.7.3\" on the \"npm\" registry.".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/.../angular5-toh/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

So where is the problem ? How can I fix this ?

I'm working on Archlinux and here are the versions :

```
$ ng version

    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 9.8.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 
...

$ yarn --version
1.5.1
```

Thanks

---

Update #1 : I've made a new attempt and the error is different.

```
$ ng new angular5-toh
  create angular5-toh/README.md (1027 bytes)
  create angular5-toh/.angular-cli.json (1247 bytes)
  [...]
  create angular5-toh/src/app/app.component.ts (207 bytes)
error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find package \"@schematics/angular@0.3.2\" required by \"@angular/cli@~1.7.3\" on the \"npm\" registry.".
Error: Couldn't find package "@schematics/package-update@0.3.2" required by "@angular/cli@~1.7.3" on the "npm" registry.
    at new MessageError (/usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:186:110)
    at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:36274:17)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (/usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:98:30)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:111:13
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
Error: Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

---

Update #2 : I've tried to *yarn install* multiple time and I obtain one of those two error.

```
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.5.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find package \"@ngtools/webpack@1.10.2\" required by \"@angular/cli@~1.7.3\" on the \"npm\" registry.".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/.../angular5-toh/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

$ yarn install
yarn install v1.5.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find package \"@schematics/angular@0.3.2\" required by \"@angular/cli@~1.7.3\" on the \"npm\" registry.".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/.../angular5-toh/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

And of course no node_modules/ directory

```
$ ls -l
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 1 fs fs   82 Mar 17 12:06 e2e
-rw-r--r-- 1 fs fs  923 Mar 17 12:06 karma.conf.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 fs fs 1297 Mar 17 12:06 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 fs fs  722 Mar 17 12:06 protractor.conf.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 fs fs 1027 Mar 17 12:06 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 1 fs fs  250 Mar 17 12:06 src
-rw-r--r-- 1 fs fs  363 Mar 17 12:06 tsconfig.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 fs fs 3012 Mar 17 12:06 tslint.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 fs fs 2321 Mar 17 12:22 yarn-error.log
```

Comment: Have you checked Angular CLI's issues to see if anyone else has this problem? Raised an issue there? SO can't really help with arbitrary third party dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

Delete the Node Modules File an make a new Npm install

Comment: Do you mean the directory node_modules/ ? I can't remove it because it does not exist.